# If $Ax=0$ for all $x\in \{b\}^{\perp}$ then prove that there exists $a\in \mathbb R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $A=a\otimes b.$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

If $Ax=0$ for all $x\in \{b\}^{\perp}$ then prove that there exists $a\in \mathbb R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $A=a\otimes b.$ Also it's given that $Ab\neq 0.$

Actually I can find a vector $a\in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ such that $A=a\otimes Ab$ because the columns or rows of $A$ span a vector space of rank $1$.

But how can I prove that $A=a \otimes b.$

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit: I think if we can get a solution of the equation $Ax=b$ then we are done. So can we get a solution of this equation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of $A$ span a vector space of dimension $1$, hence the matrix $A$, of rank $1$, can be written $A=uv^T$, for two nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$.

Let $(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$ be an orthogonal base (not necessarily orthonormal), with $e_1=b$. Then, since $Ae_i=0$ for all $i>1$ and $Ae_1\ne0$, we get that the dot product $v^Te_i$ is zero for $i>1$ and nonzero for $i=1$. That is, the only nonzero component of $v$ in the base $(e_i)_i$ is along $e_1=b$. That is, $v=\lambda b$, for some $\lambda\ne0$.

Then, with $a=\lambda u$, we have $A=uv^T=ab^T$, which you can rewrite $A=a\otimes b$.

Comment: I just have one question whether we can take $||a||=1$ or not?

Comment: @MADmind Only if you can change $||b||$ at will. If $b$ is a given, then $||a||$ is constrained by the relation $A=ab^T$.

Comment: We need $||a||=1$ i.e., $|\lambda | ||u||=1$ i.e., $ | \langle v,b \rangle | ||u||=1$ so can't we write $A$ as $uv^T$ such that $ | \langle v,b \rangle | ||u||=1$ ?

Comment: Actually this may not happen that always $||a||=1$. Suppose, for example : A=$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=(1 \ 0)^{T}$ then I think all the requisities are satisfied and here $||a||$ will not be equal to 1.

Comment: @MADmind That's exactly what I wrote above: if $A$ and $b$ are given, you can't choose $||a||$. In your example, you must have $a=(2\;0)^T$.